# Changing UIView size programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I've a UIView, I want to change the size when user touches a button.

```
CGRect newFrame = self.myview.frame;

newFrame.size.width = 200;
newFrame.size.height = 200;
[self setFrame:newFrame];

CGRect newFrame = self.searchField.frame;

newFrame.size.width = 200;
newFrame.size.height = 200;
self.searchField.frame=newFrame;
```

None of them works, don't change anything. I want to set fixed width and height to UIView.

Comment: Is this in the implementation file of the view controller?

Answer (score 87):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the size of `self.myview`. However at no point you are setting the frame of it. Instead you are trying to call `sendFrame:` on the view controller and some search field. I'm surprised, that the former one didn't give you a compiler error.

**Objective C**

```
CGRect newFrame = self.myview.frame;

newFrame.size.width = 200;
newFrame.size.height = 200;
[self.myview setFrame:newFrame];
```

**Swift**

```
var newFrame = myview.frame

newFrame.size.width = 200
newFrame.size.height = 200
myview.frame = newFrame
```

Comment: that code seems to have no affect on a UICollectionView

Comment: @Gerry: It will work on the UICollectionView. Though it will not work on the cells inside a collection view. The sizes of those are set by the layout that is used for the collection view, not by the views themselves.
Have a look at collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath from the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I had a constraint on the width of my view, so I couldn't change the width like Tim said.

What I've done : I created an outlet on my constraint, called `myviewWidthConstraint` for example. Then I used this outlet to change the width of my view like this :

```
mycell.myviewWidthConstraint.constant = newSize;
```

Comment: Just wanted to take a moment to stress the brilliance of this solution.  I took and created a pair of constraints based on the alternating anchor points I wanted to use for a given view and deactivated the one I didn't need when loading.  Now resizing in the proper manner is a simple `oldConstraint.isActive = false; newConstraint.isActive = true` away.

Answer (score 7):

Size fields are read-only, just make a new one -

```
//Set height
let f = view.frame;      //Grab current
view.frame = CGRect(x: f.origin.x, y: f.origin.y, width: f.width, height: 200);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
view.frame  = newframe;
```

or

```
view.center = newcenter;
```